# Python: I use .decode() - 'ascii' codec can't encode

Tags: python, unicode

**That seems that I've used wrong function. With `.fromstring` - there're no error messages**

```
xml_ = load() # here comes the unicode string with Cyrillic letters 

print xml_    # prints everything fine 

print type(xml_) # 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult' = unicode 

xml = xml_.decode('utf-8') # here is an error

doc = lxml.etree.parse(xml) # if I do not decode it - the same error appears here

 File "testLog.py", line 48, in <module>
    xml = xml_.decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 89-96: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If

```
xml = xml_.encode('utf-8')

doc = lxml.etree.parse(xml) # here's an error
```

or

```
xml = xml_
```

then

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 89: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I understand it right: I must decode non-ascii string into internal representation, then work with this representation and encode it back before sending to output? It seems that I do exactly this.

Input data must be in unt-8 due to the `'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'` header.

Comment: Is the error still about character encoding on etree.parse() call? what is the type of xml? etree.parse does not work on strings or unicode objects. Try etree.fromstring() instead.

Comment: @hasanyasin, it seems that you are right. :)

Comment: I will write a nice answer covering both problems hoping that you will accept is as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, using `.fromstring()` method is what was needed.

Answer (score 6):

String and Unicode objects have different types and different representations of their content in memory. Unicode is the decoded form of text while string is an encoded one.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 --

# Now, my string literals in this source file will
#    be str objects encoded in utf-8.

# In Python3, they will be unicode objects.
#    Below examples show the Python2 way.

s = 'ş'
print type(s) # prints <type 'str'>

u = s.decode('utf-8')
# Here, we create a unicode object from a string
#    which was encoded in utf-8.

print type(u) # prints <type 'unicode'>
```

As you see,

```
.encode() --> str
.decode() --> unicode
```

When we encode to or decode from strings, we need to be sure that our text should be covered in the source/target encoding. An iso-8859-1 encoded string cannot be decoded correctly with iso-8859-9.

As for the second error report in the question, `lxml.etree.parse()` works on file-like objects. To parse from strings, `lxml.etree.fromstring()` should be used.

Answer (score 2):

If your original string is unicode it only makes sense to encode it to utf-8 not decode from utf-8.

I think the xml parser can handle only xml which is ascii.

So use `xml = xml_.encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace')` to convert the unicode characters that are not in ascii to xml entitities.

Comment: @hasanyasin : I encode the unicode string to bytes in the ascii encoding. This is very well possible. The Cyrillic strings are translated into xml entities. e.g. `Ж` becomes `&#1046;`.

Answer (score 1):

The lxml library already puts things to unicode type for you. You're running into python2's unicode/bytes automatic conversion. The hint for that is that you're asking it to `decode` but you're getting an *Encode* error. It's trying to convert your utf8 string to the default bytes encoding then decode it back to unicode.

Use the .encode method on unicode objects to convert to bytes (`str` type).

Watching this will teach you a lot about how to solve this problem: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are trying to parse some web site?

Did you *validate* that the website is correct? Maybe *they* have the encoding incorrect?

Many websites are broken and rely on web browser to have *very* robust parsers. You could give beautifulsoup a try, it also is very robust.

There is the de-facto web standard that the "Charset" HTML header (which may include negotiation and relates to the Accept-Encoding you mention) is **overruled by any `<meta http-equiv=...` tag in the HTML file**!

So you might just *not* have a UTF-8 input!